# jQuery next page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hai all

i need to know how i can make next page in jQuery.

i am crating a wall, and here i have a page limit on 10, after 10 wall msg, the user shot be anable to go to the next 10 wall msg.

i have only one problem here, if i use $.getJSON the msg's load in a div tag, and when Google index my pages it only look page 1 in this wall.

i have look on history plugin in jQuery bot i don't know how i can make able when you go to page 1,2,3 and more its load fysikal url and not only load div tag.

sombady can help me here? :)

Comment: This question is really hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need Google to index your other pages, then first make your pages navigable without AJAX, ie; www.example.com/wall?page=3

Then use jQuery to "hijax" the links if you are still wanting AJAX pages. The bonus of this is that if a user doesn't have javascript installed they can still navigate through pages.